# How to split a loop into multiple column and row?

Tags: html, laravel, loops

I have a loop to display my data in table format.

```
<table>
<thead>
<th>name</th>
<th>qty</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  @foreach ($users as $user)
      @foreach ($user->displayDetails($user->id) as $d)
       <tr>
          <td>{{$d->name}}</td>
          <td>{{$d->ordered_qty}}</td>                             
       </tr>
     @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

The result output will be

```
name | qty
John   1
Lynn   1
Jack   2
```

What I am expecting is:

```
name | qty    name | qty
John   1      Lynn   1
Jack   2
```

How can I make this?

Comment: How many columns can there be max? 2? Unlimited? One for each letter of the alphabet?

Comment: you want it side by side?? what if there is another record with quantity 1??

Comment: You've [asked a similar question today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48740842/how-to-loop-item-and-divide-them-into-left-and-right-accordingly-using-bootstrap) but haven't commented and haven't chosen any answer.

Comment: Your expected result makes no sense

Comment: @btl yes, unlimited, as long as data is there.

Comment: @Sohel0415 yes, the qty will sum up based on user id and display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this: (It's much HTML splitting instead of Laravel)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>qty</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>qty</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    @foreach ($users as $key => $user)
        @foreach ($user->displayDetails($user->id) as $d)
        <td>{{$d->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$d->ordered_qty}}</td>                             
        @endforeach
    @if((@key + 1) % 2 == 0)
    </tr><tr>
    @endif
    @endforeach
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: But for the right side it will show data start from row 2.

Comment: I updated the index used when modding.